# Adding hyperlink to a table element, carrying its informations [PHP]

Tags: php, html, html-table

Being a huge PHP newbie I find myself stuck here.
I have an HTML table for a videogame store filled with elements taken from my database.
The point is, I want to be able to add a link to the game title. Moreover I want the link to direct to some "gamePage.php", a php page used for every videogame but of course showing different infos for each game (title, console etc).
The fact is that not only I can't add the hyperlink, but I have no clue on how to carry the videogame infos when I click on a link (even managing to add the link, all I would manage to do would be redirecting the user to a blank gamePage.php with no title).

This is the code I use to fill the table (the restore function fills my table):

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <div>
   <table width = "550px" height = "300px" border="2" >
     <tr bgcolor="#5f9ea0">
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Console</td>
        <td>Genre</td>
        <td>Price</td>
     </tr>
     <?php
        $conn = @pg_connect('dbname=project user=memyself password=project');
        function search(){
           <!-- Work in progress -->
        }
        function restore(){
        $query = "SELECT v.Title , c.Consolename , g.Genrename , v.Price  
                  FROM vg_shop.videogame v, vg_shop.console c, vg_shop.genre g
                  WHERE v.Console=c.IDConsole AND v.Genre=g.IDGenre";
        $result = pg_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
            echo pg_last_error();
            exit();
        }

        while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",
    $myrow['title'], $myrow['consolename'], $myrow['genrename'], $myrow['price']);
                        }

        }
        <!-- some code -->
 </body>
</html>
```

At first i tried to do this

```
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            printf ("<tr><td><a href="gamePage.php">%s</a></td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", 
  $myrow['title'], $myrow['consolename'], $myrow['genrename'], $myrow['price']);
```

But all I get is a white page, there's some syntax error I don't get.
And, even if it worked, I still can't carry at least the videogame PID through the gamePage link

Comment: normally you'd create a link passing the ID.. ie `gamepage.php?id=12` then on that page you fetch the game belonging to that ID and display it. A good reason is that you then don't have to select * on the list (you may only need the id and title), and then you can select the full object when/if the user needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you're managing to go to `gamepage.php` somehow.

So you need to add some sort of `identifier` to your link you that you could do some query on the `gamepage.php` by using that `identifier` to get info for that particular game.

```
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("<tr><td><a href='gamePage.php?id=%s'>%s</a></td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow['id'],  $myrow['title'], $myrow['consolename'], $myrow['genrename'], $myrow['price']);
```

**Note**: I assume that you're picking `$myrow['id']` from database as well.

now on your `gamepage.php` do following.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vg_shop.videogame WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = pg_query($sql);
if($result){
    $result = pg_fetch_assoc($result):
    //...
    // echo "Name: ".$result['Title'];
    //    other fields
}
```

`$result` will have all info about that particular game that was clicked, you can display all as you want.

Cheers :)